How do I install ShengBTE software?
I am totally new user in Ubuntu. For research purpose, I need to install ShengBTE software. In the following I copied the texts which is important for compilation. According to the texts, I downloaded the software and went to src directory, it contains Makefile and others f90 extension files.There is a arch.make.example outside the src directory, I move that to src directory and then just wrote 'make' in the terminal, but its not worked.

"To compile the code it is enough to run make in the Src subdirectory
of the distribution, but a suitable arch.make must be present in that
directory. An example is provided as arch.make.example. As a minimum,
$MPIFC must contain a valid command to compile Fortran 90 code with
MPI directives, while the combination of $LDFLAGS and $LIBS must
contain any linker flags required in order to link against an
implementation of LAPACK and against Atsushi Togo's spglib. ShengBTE
uses some Fortran 2003 extensions, most notably its new syntax for
array initialization, and a recent Fortran compiler is required that
supports them; modern versions of both gfortran and ifort are known to
work. To compile with OpenMP threading enabled the relevant compiler
flag must also be used. After compilation succeeds, a ShengBTE binary
will be created in the root directory of the distribution. This
executable takes no command-line options and accepts no input from the
terminal."

Here is the arch.make.example
export FFLAGS=-traceback -debug -O2 -static_intel -qopenmp
export LDFLAGS=-L/home/user/REPOSITORY/spglib/lib -lsymspg
export MPIFC=mpif90
MKL=$(MKLROOT)/lib/em64t/libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a -Wl,--start-group   \
$(MKLROOT)/lib/em64t/libmkl_intel_lp64.a                \
 $(MKLROOT)/lib/em64t/libmkl_sequential.a               \
 $(MKLROOT)/lib/em64t/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -lpthread -lm
export LAPACK=$(MKL)
export LIBS=$(LAPACK)

Would anyone please guide step by step, how can install that software?

The arch.make.example file appears to be targeted towards building a statically linked executable using the Intel ifort toolchain. However I was able to build a dynamically linked version using gfortran on Ubuntu 24.04 using the following steps:

install gfortran plus the OpenMPI and required MKL development packages
sudo apt install gfortran libopenmpi-dev \
  libmkl-core libmkl-threading-dev libmkl-interface-dev


install the Spglib development package
sudo apt install libsymspg-dev 


create a Src/arch.make file based on the provided arch.make.example with the following minimal differences
$ diff -by arch.make.example Src/arch.make 
export FFLAGS=-traceback -debug -O2 -static_intel -qopen      | export FFLAGS=-g -O2 -fPIC -fopenmp
export LDFLAGS=-L/home/user/REPOSITORY/spglib/lib -lsyms      | export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lsymspg
export MPIFC=mpif90                                             export MPIFC=mpif90
MKL=$(MKLROOT)/lib/em64t/libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a -Wl,--st      | MKL=$(MKLROOT)/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a -W
$(MKLROOT)/lib/em64t/libmkl_intel_lp64.a                      | $(MKLROOT)/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmkl_intel_lp64.so
 $(MKLROOT)/lib/em64t/libmkl_sequential.a                     |  $(MKLROOT)/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmkl_sequential.so
 $(MKLROOT)/lib/em64t/libmkl_core.a -Wl,--end-group -lpt      |  $(MKLROOT)/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmkl_core.so -Wl,--end-gro
export LAPACK=$(MKL)                                            export LAPACK=$(MKL)
export LIBS=$(LAPACK)                                           export LIBS=$(LAPACK)



You should then be able to simply make inside the Src subdirectory as instructed.
If you really need a statically built executable then it will be more work, since the Ubuntu packages do not appear to provide archive (static) libraries libmkl_core.a or libsymspg.a.

Ubuntu 22.04 has the .a files:$ apt-file search libsymspg.a
libsymspg-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsymspg.a
$ apt-file search libmkl_core.a
libmkl-computational-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmkl_core.a

@ubfan1 thanks - it looks like 24.04 libmkl-computational-dev also has the libmkl_core.a lib (don't know how I missed that) so it's only libsymspg-dev that's different. I also noticed I left (static) libmkl_lapack95_lp64.a in the build - I will take another look and see I can do a build with fewer makefile changes on 22.04

@steeldriver I am using Ubuntu 24.04 on virtual box.
It seems like you changed the directory in arch.make. For example: you have used lsymspg as follows
export LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lsymspg
I just checked my directory and for me it should be as
export LDFLAGS=-L/home/hasan/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spglib/lib -lsymspg
My question is, Do I have to change the directories accordingly for MKL? How can I find those directories in easy commands and paste it to arch.make?
Thank you!

@Md.JahidHasanSagor if you installed the MKL packages from the Ubuntu repository and your VM architecture is x86_64 then the paths I used should be correct for you. If you installed MKL some other way (e.g. via anaconda) then you will need to figure it out yourself - sorry

@steeldriver you are right. I just copied what you wrote in arch.make and ran make, I didn't get any error message. It seems software compiled successfully then. Thank you!
One more thing you were talking about static linking, Can you give me some hints how I can do that?

OK well that's a question about usage rather than installing - you will need to consult the Input files section of the README.md file. There are some example CONTROL files in the Tests-xxxx subdirectories so I suggest you have a play with some of them e.g. cd Test-flags then ../ShengBTE
